# Files created via file api are not visible in mediastore api (Android API 29-30)

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore, fileapi, scoped-storage

In my application, video files were created and saved to the Movies directory. I used File Api for this.

```
private val dir: File by lazy {
        File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
            MOVIES_SUB_DIR_NAME
        ).apply { mkdirs() }
}

fun createFile(name: String): String = File(dir, name).absolutePath
```

In android api 29 we switched to scoped storage. And now they began to use MediaStore Api. Now I am creating files via `contentResolver.insert`. And I get them through him too `contentResolver.query`

```
override fun getVideoMetaDataList(mimeType: String): List<MetaData> {
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION
        )
        return context.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY),
            projection,
            "${MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE} LIKE ?",
            arrayOf(mimeType),
            null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
            val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE)
            val dateModifiedColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)
            val durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)

            mutableListOf<MetaData>().apply {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    add(
                        MetaData(
                            name = cursor.getString(nameColumn) ?: continue,
                            uriString = ContentUris.withAppendedId(videoUri, id).toString(),
                            size = cursor.getLong(sizeColumn),
                            lastModification = cursor.getString(dateModifiedColumn) ?: continue,
                            duration = cursor.getLong(durationColumn)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        } ?: emptyList()
}
```

But through MediaStore Api I cannot see files added through FileApi. These are old files created in previous versions of the application that I need. They just don't return in the `query` method

If you update the files (for example, change the name) in the Files application, the files become visible

Comment: `But through MediaStore Api I cannot see files added through FileApi.` ?? Unclear. OR you create a file using FIle api OR you let the MediaStore create a file. Not both. Please explain what you mean and tell which Android version on used device.

Comment: Checked on `Android 10 and 11`. I used to create files via `FileApi`, when I go to the `MediaStore Api` I don't have access to those files. They do not return on `query`

Comment: `I used to create files via FileApi` ? Are you telling that you do not use FIle api now on Android 10 and 11? Or are you telling that you still only create files using File api? As for me you suggest that you use the MediaStore now to create your files..

Comment: Now I am not creating files via FileApi. But I need files that were created earlier through this Api. But they are not in MediaStore Api

Comment: Did they disappear from the MediaStore? Then what happened in mean time? Was your device updated or so?  (You see it is pretty unclear what exactlty your problem is. Sorry for that. Please explain better your scenario).

Comment: Can you list the files in Movies/MOVIES_SUB_DIR_NAME in the classic way? With File.listFiles() ? (You will get different results for Android 10 and 11 so try for both devices please.) On an Android 11 device your app should be able to list them.

Comment: I am creating files in an old version of the application using FileApi. In the new version, I set targetSdkApi 30, and move to work with files via MediaStore Api, because on Android 10, work via File Api is not available. Using MediaStore Api I cannot get my old files (created via FileApi). By installing a new version of the application, I can only get new files (or files created by other applications), the files that I created in the previous version of the application are no longer available

Comment: Yes, most of that i had understood already. Please do the test i suggested and be aware that Android 10 and Android 11 devices behave differently.

Comment: If I use `File.listFiles()` I can get files on Android 11, but on Android 10 I get null

Comment: Indeed. That was to be expected. I do not know why they are not in the MediaStore. (Did you deinstall the app first?). But i know how you can get them in the media store on Android 11. Just let them be scanned by the media store scanner.

Comment: Thank you. The application was not removed. And there remains a problem with Android 10 where I cannot get the file path. Can I scan the directory or are there any other options?

Comment: Maybe you can just ask the media scanner to scan a directory providing path to directory. I forgot if it is possible. Just google and try. Even if you have no access to that directory yourself on Android 10. Try. Further: rebooting your device should show them up too -after a while- is my experience.

Comment: Yes, indeed you can scan the directory, thanks you helped me a lot

Comment: After all i think they were never in the media store. So it has nothing to do with updating or Android version.